# Configuring Material UI with Next.js and react-apollo; correct usage of getDataFromTree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, react-apollo

I have an existing application in which I've encountered a problem.
The root of the problem, as far as I know, lies in a broken Apollo query (for example, when trying to spread `data` whilest it's still `undefined`). This leads to a wierd UI, in which there are humongous icons and to a **warning of such kind**:

`Warning: Prop className did not match. Server: "MuiSvgIcon-root-69" Client: "MuiSvgIcon-root"`

After some research, I found out that the reason of this may be the `disableGeneration` prop which should be set to `true` for performance reasons, but I also suspect that if it's turned on then MUI skips the className generation and yields correct classnames as the result.

The question is: what is the correct way to use it, or is there any other way to fix this issue? My stacks is as follows:

- next.js 9.1.1
- material UI 4.6.0
- react-apollo 3.1.2

I have tried several combinations of using `StylesProvider` and `ServerStyleSheets`, though I haven't managed to get the job done. Currently I'm using this in `_document.js`:

```
const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets({
  injectFirst: true
});
```

And this is the way I use `getDataFromTree`, though it looks quite odd to me:

```
const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets({
  disableGeneration: true
});

await getDataFromTree(sheets.collect(<AppTree {...appProps} />));
```

I had done a lot of googling but couldn't find a concise result of how to use SSR with Apollo & Material. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: DId you manage to find a solution? I'm facing the same exact problem, with the same stack, and I can't quite understand how to solve this problem